# What does a.a.s stand for in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I've been trying to read and understand the "Analysis of the parallel peeling algorithm: a short proof" paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.7326), but one portion that slightly bothers me is the a.a.s acronym. I was wondering what it stood for, specifically in the following context

> Assume $k, r \geq 2$, $(k, r) \neq (2, 2)$ and $c < c_{r, k}$. Then a.a.s $s(\mathcal{H}_r(n, c/n^{r - 1})) \leq (a_{r, k}^* + o(1))\log \log n$, where $a_{r, k}^* = 1 / \log(k(r - 1)/r)$.

Where $\mathcal{H}_r(n, c/n^{r - 1})$ is a hypergraph with $n$ vertices, each edge connecting $r$ vertices, and $c/n^{r - 1}$ representing the edge density of the graph. I've looked around the internet, but all I managed to find were Angle Angle Side for triangles, and other unrelated results. I have also looked through math stack exchange, and others seem to use the acronym for graph theory specifically, though I'm not sure if that's necessarily true. I was unable to discern from the other posts what a.a.s is supposed to mean.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Links to other posts using this acronym

[Random graph contains no $C_4$ a.a.s.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4374886/random-graph-contains-no-c-4-a-a-s)

[Random graph with $p \ll n^{-1+\epsilon}$ a.a.s has no subgraph with $k$ vertices with at least $k+1$ edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027258/random-graph-with-p-ll-n-1-epsilon-a-a-s-has-no-subgraph-with-k-vertice)

[Chromatic number of Random graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309216/chromatic-number-of-random-graph)

Comment: *"I have also looked through math stack exchange, and others seem to use the acronym for graph theory specifically"* Please link to these other uses.

Comment: I've seen this acronym in the context of random graphs. It meant "asymptotically almost surely", with some rigorous definition I could check if you think it might be it. It was used for some asymptotic properties of those random graphs.

Comment: @Esgeriath Hmmmm, this is also a random graph (technically hypergraph, but I assume it would work the same). I considered it and it seems to make sense, but I would need to read a little further to be sure.

Comment: Well, I checked it. In book "Random Graphs" by S. Janson, T. Łuczak & A. Ruciński:

We say that an event $\mathcal E_n$, describing a property of a random structure depending on a parameter $n$, holds asymptotically almost surely (abbreviated a.a.s.) if $\mathbb P(\mathcal E_n) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @Esgeriath Thank you so much! That definition helps out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up corroborating the response in the comments, I was reading a paper today on arXiv that used this notation and then clarified in the first paragraph that "a.a.s." meant "asymptotically with probability 1." The [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.09044) is titled

> Maximum sparse induced subgraphs of the binomial random
> graph with given number of edges

by D. Kamaldinov, A. Skorkin, and M. Zhukovskii.